# CodeIgniter MySQL multiple version and compatibility

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, compatibility

I was wondering for the Codeigniter 2.2 framework if I use a MySQL version 5.0.XX is it possible later to transfer over to a newer version of MySQL (5.6) later with the same app and not run into problems (incompatibility issues).

I am asking this because in two months we will be buying a new server, but I need to get stuff started. I am aware that Codeigniter 2.2 works for multiple version of PHP and that the requirements for MySQL is version 4.1+ but would transferring cause any problems?

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html

Comment: Yes, you will be fine. The binary file format of the database is probably incompatible between 5.0 and 5.6, but you can do a SQL dump and import easily. This can be done from phpMyAdmin, or on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using codeigniter 2.2 with both versions of MYSQL that you have mentioned i.e. MySQL 5.2 in production and MySQL 5.6 in my local server. I never had any issues. You will be fine.